# React Router 4 - No Header for Homepage only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I seem to be facing a simple issue but would like to know the best way to solve it.

I have the following classical router with RR4:

```
const AppRouter = () => (
<BrowserRouter>
    <div className="content">
        <Header />
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Index} exact={true} />
            <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} exact={true} />
            <Route path="/account" component={Account} exact={true} />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact={true}/>
            <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} exact={true}/>
            <Route path="/*" component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
);
```

And I would like to have a case on my Index Root where it does not show the header and footer if the user is not connected but still shows these on any other page (whether connected or not) and on Index when connected. Not sure how to manage this probably simple case. Anyone could help ? thanks in advance !

Comment: what do you mean by connected?

Comment: I'm using Meteor so when a user is connected to its account through meteor but it could be any Session variable as a boolean. If true show header footer if false don't show. i don't think the logic relies in the reason when to show or not but maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If the connected state is in something like redux you can just have the header and footer read the state and return null. the header can get hold of the current url props with **withRouter**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class HeaderComponent extends Component  {

    const { match, location, history } = this.props

    render() {
        if(!connected && location.pathname === '/') return null;

        return <div>Header</div>
    }
}
const Header = withRouter(HeaderComponent)
```

Comment: Problem is that I don't want to have Header : show if connected don't if not on every page, juste on the './' route

Comment: Use withRouter combined with your connected state in the header component https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md